# Better way of filtering data with Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I'm trying to build a web chat application. I'm utilizing Firebase as a backend and Vuex. I have a logged in user, conversations, messages and users. The conversation document - in Firebase's Cloud Firestore - has an array of the messages belonging to that conversation and another of the list of users who belong to that conversation.

When my conversation container component is opened, I retrieve the conversations through an action and commit the changes:

Action:

```
async get({commit, rootState}) {
    let convoRef = rootState.db.collection('conversations');
    let conversations = await convoRef.get();

    conversations.forEach(conversation => commit('SET_CONVERSATION', {conversation}))
}
```

Mutation:

```
SET_CONVERSATION(state, {conversation}) {
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    const data = conversation.data();
    let users = data.users;

    _.forEach(users, function (value, key) {
        if (value.id === user.uid) {
            state.all = {
                ...state.all,
                [conversation.id]: {
                    id: conversation.id,
                    users: data.users,
                    name: data.name,
                    created: data.created,
                    messages: []
                }
            };

            state.allIds.push(conversation.id);
        }
    });
}
```

I filter out the appropriate conversations with

```
 if (value.id === user.uid)
```

Where user.uid is the id of the logged in user.

Problem with this approach is that I'm getting all the conversations that do no belong to the logged in user and then filtering. Is there a way to filter out the data before issuing the mutation? I tried going through Firestore's docs but there doesn't seem to be a way to natively filter out documents based on values in nested collections in said document. Thanks.

Comment: These docs describe how firebase data can be filtered: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query
Does that help?

Comment: If you want more information on more complex queries, you can follow this playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s
But don't expect too much, unfortunately, some solutions are quite painful to watch...

Comment: @glutengo OP is using Cloud Firestore, while your link is for the Realtime Database.

Comment: @Frisbetarian: Please show what your collection and documents look like, as it's rather tricky to derive that from the code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my bad, thanks for the hint, here's the documentation bit for firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data but

Comment: Sorry for not being clear: I am looking for your **documents** and collection.